# Guarantees on pointer size in C++

Tags: c++

In C++, what guarantees are there, if any, for two types T1 and T2 so that

```
sizeof(T1*) == sizeof(T2*)
```

will always be true? It's not guaranteed, for example, that char* and int* will be the same size on all systems.

Comment: The pointer size has to do with the addresses space, not the used object

Comment: The existence of [`std::uintptr_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) implies that `sizeof(T*) <= sizeof(std::uintptr_t)` though I'm not sure that includes function pointers.

Comment: ...or method pointers.

Comment: ...or mouse pointers.

Comment: Depends on the processor.  The 16-bit processors that have a 16-bit address space would have a 2 byte pointer.   Some processors have "near" pointer that is one byte.  Other processors have 24 bit points; while some processors have 64 or more bits.  There is no standard.